# Ceiling brackets produce too much space in some cases?

Tags: spacing, braces

Why does this expression:

```
$\left\lceil \left. n \middle/ \ell \right. \right\rceil$
```

(which I get from

```
$\ceil{\hfrac{n}{ell}}$
```

) produce so much space between the `\left\lceil` and the `n` (especially compared to what I perceive, albeit perhaps by a trick of the mind, as a more moderate amount of space from the `\ell` to the `\right\rceil`) ?

[image]

(image obtained using ([this online previewer](http://www.tlhiv.org/ltxpreview/).)

I don't want to force things with a `\!` or some similar command, since I don't want to get bitten in other case.

---

<sub>Note: The expression above is due to the following code:</sub>

```
\newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil}
\newcommand{\hfrac}[2]{\left .#1 \middle/ #2 \right.}

% etc. etc.

$\ceil{\hfrac{n}{\ell}}$
```

Comment: The extra whitespace -- the precise amount is `\nulldelimiterspace` -- before `n` and after `\ell` comes from the `\left.` and `\right.` directives. What's their purpose -- other than to insert extra whitespace?

Comment: @Mico: I thought I needed them to have a `\middle/` - but as egreg suggests, I guess I don't.

Answer (score 1):

A "trick of the mind" may indeed be at work here. What you perceive to be an asymmetry is entirely due to the rather different vertical heights of `n` and `\ell`, along with the fact that `\ell` "leans" to the right whereas `\rceil` "leans" (visually) to the left. (Try `\lceil n/m \rceil` to verify the "trick of the mind" issue.)

At any rate, I'd say that using the pair of `\left.` and `\right.` directives inserts too much whitespace (in the amount of `\nulldelimiterspace`, in case you're curious). To achieve visual balance for the `n/\ell` material inside the "ceiling" brackets, I'd insert only *half* a thinspace, i.e., `\mkern1.5mu`, to the right of `\ell`, and I would not insert any whitespace to the left of `n`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for "\DeclarePairedDelimiter" macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ceil}{\lceil}{\rceil}
\begin{document}
$\left\lceil \left. n \middle/ \ell \right. \right\rceil$

% reproduce the preceding output without using "\left." and "\right."
$\left\lceil \kern\nulldelimiterspace n \middle/ \ell \kern\nulldelimiterspace \right\rceil$ 


\medskip
% undo the effects of "\left." and "\right."
$\left\lceil \left. \kern-\nulldelimiterspace n \middle/ \ell \right. \kern-\nulldelimiterspace \right\rceil$

$\left\lceil n \middle/ \ell  \right\rceil$

\medskip
$\ceil*{n\middle/\ell\mkern1.5mu}$ % if you insist on auto-sizing the delimiters...

$\ceil{n/\ell\mkern1.5mu}$

\medskip
$\lceil n/\ell\mkern1.5mu \rceil$
\end{document}
```

Comment: So what's your advice for the general case? which of these options?

Comment: @einpoklum - My advice would be, first, to set up a `\ceil` macro using the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` device, with no spacing adjustment by default on either the left or the right. Second, use spacing adjustments only when needed; such a need arises, in my opinion, only for the letters `d`, `l` and `\ell`. In the answer above, I've used `\mkern1.5mu`; depending on your aesthetic preferences, you may prefer `\mkern2mu`. Still speaking for myself, I think that `\,` ("thinspace", equivalent to `\mkern3mu`) would be too much of a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for `\left.` and `\right.`, as you have `\middle` in between `\left\lceil` and `\right\rceil`.

Any `\left.` and `\right.` command inserts horizontal space in the amount of `\nulldelimiterspace` (0.5pt, by default).

Actually you need no `\left` and `\right`, but just a manual adjustment which is usually required when a tall symbol leans onto a delimiter; for instance, here or when you have something like `(1+\sqrt{2}\,)`; other cases are `\biggl(\,\sum_{i=1}^n` and similar ones.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % not really needed here but recommended anyhow

\begin{document}

$\left\lceil \left. n \middle/ l \right. \right\rceil$

$\left\lceil n \middle/ l \right\rceil$

$\lceil n / l \rceil$

$\lceil n / l \,\rceil$

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, the output from the second and third input are exactly the same, showing `\left` and `\right` are unnecessary (they also add unwanted space, in this case).

Note: I consider `\ell` a very ugly symbol; the letter was handwritten that way in old typescripts for distinguishing it from `1`, but with good fonts and typesetting it's by no means necessary any longer.

Comment: Actually, the `\left.` and `\right.` come from a command which only has the fraction (the `middle/`); then another command does wraps that with the ceil brackets; see my note at the bottom of the question.

Comment: About the `$\ell$` - I wouldn't mind not using it, but: 1. `$l$` looks like `$1$` in the source code to some extent. 2. `$l$` still looks like a weird stick with a hook, if not actually a 1, in the output. 3. The top wedge-like serif of the `$\ell$` makes it look like it can't be in the same font as the `$n$`, all of whose edges are just not wedge-like.

Comment: @einpoklum I see no use for `\left` and `\right` in those macros.

Comment: Ok, I guess I made the incorrect assumption that they were necessary in the general case.

Comment: Oh, wait, that's not true! I _do_ need the `\left.` and `\right.` in the fraction macro - otherwise I get an error for the `\middle/` !

Comment: @einpoklum And what's  `\middle` for?